# Find the sum of any two given integers

Tags: methods, sum, addition

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IRVE.png][1]I want to solve this problem through multiple methods. But I am unable to solve this issue. I have created two methods (One method is for taking input from users two perform addition and the other one method is executing the logic to perform addition), also I have passed parameters throug[https://i.stack.imgur.com/RE4Ma.png][2]h both the methods.

ISSUE:

C:\Users\souvi\Desktop\myProgrammingWorld\JAVA\MyProgrammingWorld\src\BasicJavaProgram.java:7:9

java: method takingInput in class BasicJavaProgram cannot be applied to given types;
required: int,int
found:    no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

package com.apnacollege;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PerformAddition {

```
private static int num1;
private static int num2;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    whatToDo();
    takingInputsForUsers();
    System.out.println("The answer is : " + calculateSum());
}

static void whatToDo() {
    
    System.out.print("Enter any two positive integers to perform adition : ");
}

static void takingInputsForUsers() {
    
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    num1 = scan.nextInt();
    num2 = scan.nextInt();
    scan.close();
}

static int calculateSum() {
    
    int sum = num1 + num2;
    return sum;
}
```

}

Comment: I know this approach, but I want to solve this problem through simple user defined methods (One method for taking inputs of two integers from user and other one will perform the addition logic). Then I call both the methods inside the main method for execution.

Answer (score 0):

**Click on the link --**[Here is my answer, I have solved my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF5NO.png)